# In PyroCMS access values defined in language file of a particular module in metadata file

Tags: codeigniter, content-management-system, themes, pyrocms

I currently towards the end of the project but stuck at one thing. I have user module and in that there is language file called as user_lan, For some requirement I need to  access the value defined in that file from **metadata.html**  of themes/partial/ folder.

Any suggestion.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that lang file is already loaded then you can access it with:

```
{{ helper:lang line="foo:bar" }}
```

http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/plugins/helper